# how can i notify me when input is change?

Tags: javascript, notifications

The program needs to notify when input is changed. Below is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myfunction = setInterval(function(){
        $('input').change(function(){                 
    });
    $.post("getvalue.php",function(callback){
        $(notify.createNotification("NOTIFICATION", {body:"<?php echo $arrb; ?>", icon: "../src/func/notif/icon.jpg"})).html(callback);
        });  
    clearInterval(myfunction)  },1000);  
});
```

Comment: You need to actually put some code in your input change handler on line 3.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `change` event handler, you've just bound the `change` event handler but you're not doing anything when the event occur.
2. Call function `notify` when the value of `input` is changed
3. There is no need of using `setInterval`
4. If you want to use `setInterval` use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` as you're clearing it when the callback is called.
5. Don't use `callback` as the name of the response variable, use it as `response`(*for better naming convention*)

Ex:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {

    clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

Is equivalent to

```
setTimeout(function () {

}, 1000);
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function notify() {
        $.post("getvalue.php", function (response) {

            $(notify.createNotification("NOTIFICATION", {
                body: "<?php echo $arrb; ?>",
                icon: "../src/func/notif/icon.jpg"
            })).html(response);

        });
    }

    $('input').change(notify);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the .change handler out of the set interval and call it once you have created your input in the DOM, typically on page load is fine so your script should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').change(function () {
        console.log("any input changed because I hooked all input elements on my page");
    });

    var myfunction = setInterval(function () {

        $.post("getvalue.php", function (callback) {

            $(notify.createNotification("NOTIFICATION", {
                body: "<?php echo $arrb; ?>",
                icon: "../src/func/notif/icon.jpg"
            })).html(callback);

        });
        clearInterval(myfunction);
    }, 1000);
});
```

I'm not sure what your notify function is supposed to do, but it doesn't look much correct other than it will get called once after 1000ms when the page is ready.

Goodluck.